# How to generate identifiers in a distributed system with low probability of duplicates?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I need to generate identifiers in a distributed system.

Duplicates will be detected by the system and will cause the operation that created that identifier to fail. I need to minimize the probability of failing operations by generating identifiers with low collision probability.

I'd also like to be able to describe mathematically how likely it is that a duplicate number is generated. I'm not sure what such a description would look like, preferably I'd like to know the `X` in something like:

> When generating 1000 random numbers per second for 10 years no more than X duplicates should have been generated.

These random numbers can only have 35 significant bits. The system is written in C# and runs on top of Microsoft's .NET platform.

So this is actually two questsions in one (but I guess they depend on each other):

1. What component/pattern should I use to generate identifiers?
2. How can I compute the `X` value?

For (1) I see the following candidates:

- [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx)

The fact that I need numbers to have 35 significant bits is not a problem when it comes to generating values as it is fine to generate a larger number and then just extracting 35 of those bits. However, it do affect the mathematical computation i presume.

**UPDATE**

I can see now that 35-bits aren't nearly enough for my description above. I don't really need 1 number per millisecond for 10 years. That was an overstatement.

What I really need is a way to distributively generate identifiers that have 35 significant bits with as low probability of a conflict as possible. As time goes by the system will "clean up" identifiers so that it is possible for the same number to be used again without it causing a failure.

I understand that I could of course implement some kind of centralized counter. But I would like to be able to avoid that if possible. I want to minimize the number of network operations needed to maintain the identifiers.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the 35-bit requirement?  That's a very odd size.

Comment: The identifier will be part of a 64-bit address. The remaining bits are reserved for an "offset" within the identified "segment".

Comment: I'm not sure extracting part of GUID will guarantee an even distribution, but most liely it will

Comment: The standard platform function to create GUIDs does not produce uniformly distributed values.

Comment: Version 4 GUIDs are random

Comment: Maybe [Erics article](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses) can help you.

Comment: Is it sufficient to have the distributed nodes agree on different starting prefixes, then use an auto-incremented id for the remainder?  For instance, reserve 10 bits to allow at max 1024 nodes, then use the remaining 25 bits for an auto-incrementing id, allowing ~33 million ids per node.

Comment: @DanBryant: Yes, that could very well work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wanting to generate 1000 numbers each second for 10 years. So you will generate

```
1000*60*60*365*10 = 315360000000
```

You want to use numbers with 35 bits. There are

```
2**35 = 34359738368
```

The minimum number of duplicates that you will generate is 315360000000 - 34359738368 which equals 281000261632. That is a lower bound on X. This is self-evident. Suppose by some amazing freak that you manage to sample each and every possible value from the 2**35 available. Then every other sample you make is a duplicate.

I guess we can safely conclude that 35 bits is not enough.

As far as generating good quality pseudo random numbers, it should be fairly obvious that `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` the best choice of the three that you present.

If you really want uniqueness that I suggest that you do the following:

1. Allocate to each distributed node a unique range of IDs.
2. Have each node allocate uniquely from that pool of IDs values. For instance, the node starts at the first value and increments the ID by one every time it is asked to generate a new one.

This is really the best strategy if uniqueness matters. But you will likely need to dedicate more bits for your IDs.

Comment: I like the idea of a centralized "ID pool" from which nodes allocate sequences. Is there a known best practice / pattern for this? For example how to handle "unused" IDs - returning them to the pool?

Comment: @MårtenWikström I don't know. Not my area of expertise. Dan appears to be the man that knows the most. I'd poke him

Answer (score 2):

Since the probability of collisions steadily increases with a random allocation as you use up more addresses, the system steadily degrades in performance.  There is also the looming specter of a non-zero probability of your random selection never terminating because it never chooses a non-conflicting id (PRNGs have cycle lengths for any given seed much smaller than their theoretical full range of output.)  Whether this is a problem in practice of course depends on how saturated you expect your address space to be in the long run.

If the IDs don't need to be random, then you almost certainly want to rely on some form of coordination to assign IDs (such as partitioning the address space or using a coordinating manager of some sort to assign IDs) rather than creating random numbers and reconciling collisions after they happen.  It will be easier to implement, probably more performant and will allow better saturation of your address space.

---

In response to comment:

The design for a specific mechanism of coordination depends on a lot of factors, such as how many nodes you expect to have, how flexible you need to be in regards to adding/dropping nodes, how long the IDs need to remain unique (i.e. what is your strategy for managing ID lifetime), etc.  It's a complex problem that warrants a careful analysis of your expected use cases, including a look at your future scalability requirements.  A simple partioning scheme is sufficient if your number of nodes and/or number of IDs is small, but if you need to scale to larger volumes, it's a much more challenging problem, perhaps requiring more complex allocation strategies.

One possible partitioning design is that you have a centralized manager that allocates IDs in blocks.  Each node can then freely increment IDs within that block and only needs to request a new block when it runs out.  This can scale well if you expect your ID lifetime to correlate with age, as that generally means that whole blocks will be freed up over time.  If ID lifetime is more randomly distributed, though, this could potentially lead to fragmentation and exhaustion of available blocks.  So, again, it's a matter of understanding your requirements so that you can design for the scale and usage patterns your application requires.

Comment: Could you point me to a pattern/algorithm for such coordination? I rather tolerate collisions over a more costly scheme that guarantee no collisions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `random numbers` in your case: the **[Birthday Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)** states that 1st collistion will be at

```
  sqrt(2 * N)
```

in your case:

```
  sqrt(2 * 2^35) = sqrt(2^36) = 2^18 = 250000 items before the 1st collistion
```

So `GUID`-based value is the best choice.

Comment: Why GUID is better if he anyway is going to extract only 35 bits from it?

Comment: Yes, aren't those just random too?

Comment: GUID is not random, it's based on MAC address, Current DateTime etc.

Comment: But not the one in .NET?

Comment: You cannot extract bits from a guid.  It completely loses its ability to be unique.

Comment: The birthday paradox does not state when the first collision will be. It makes statements concerning the probabilities of encountering collisions. The first collision could be on the second sample.

Comment: Not all Guids are based on MAC address.  Version 4 Guids are random.  .NET 4 supports Version 4 Guids.  Though I'm not sure about earlier versions of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think for your particular problem **all those random numbers providers will work relatively the same** - all should generate nearly ideal even distribution of values.

I heard GUID generation includes MAC address as part of generation, so it might influence some part more than other, but I'm not sure. Most likely it is even distribute as well, but you must check that before relying on it.

The main question you should answer is do you really need random numbers, or consequtive is fine? Maybe **consequtive addresses will work better and have better performance because of caching**? So it might be good to distribute address space among your machines and have full guarantee when collision will be occured and handle it appropriately?

Comment: Yes, they don't need to be random. I've updated my question. They need to have low probability of conflict in a distributed environment.

Comment: In that case consequtive addresses should work really well for you. You always know what addresses are free and used ans spend only 2 64-bit values for that. And you always can erase the oldest addresses cyclically

Comment: But consecutive addresses requires a centralized counter right? I'm looking for another solution if possible.

Comment: Not nesassarily single counder. You can split address space across few counters (100 for example) and then allocate those blocks for each machine in distributed system (each machine will maintain it's counter on it's own without synchronization). When it used all it's address space, it may request next address block. When all blocks are full, you need to decide which to erase.